# ldap query in python

Tags: python, json, script, ldap

quiero conectar en mi host ldap y hacer esta busqueda con python :

```
ldapsearch -x -D 'cn=ldapadm,dc=sanchez,dc=com' -W                 -b 'cn=Total,cn=Connections,cn=Monitor' -s base '(objectClass=*)' '*' '+'
Enter LDAP Password:
```

por terminal esa busqueda me devuelve esto, me gustaría ver si poder coger esos datos y mostrarlos en json :

```
# LDIF extendido
#
# LDAPv3
# base <cn=Total,cn=Conexiones,cn=Monitor> con alcance baseObject
# filtro: (objectClass=*)
# solicitando: * +
#

# Total, Conexiones, Monitor
dn: cn=Total,cn=Conexiones,cn=Monitor
objectClass: monitorCounterObject
structuralObjectClass: monitorCounterObject
cn: Total
creatorsName:
modifiersName:
createTimestamp: 20210726111156Z
modifyTimestamp: 20210726111156Z
monitorCounter: 1031
entryDN: cn=Total,cn=Conexiones,cn=Monitor
subschemaSubentry: cn=Subesquema
tieneSubordinados: FALSE

# Resultado de la búsqueda
búsqueda: 2
resultado: 0 Éxito

# numResponses: 2
# numEntries: 1
```

alguno sabe como podría hacerlo?

Answer (score 1):

La siguiente función recibe una respuesta ldap como texto y devuelve un JSON con los valores:

```
def to_json(texto):
    dicc = {}
    for linea in texto.split('\n'):
        try:
            key, value = linea.split(":", 1)
            dicc[key] = value.strip()
        except ValueError:
            pass
    return json.dumps(dicc)
```

La función recibe un texto multilínea. El `for` recorre cada línea. Por cada una se intenta dividirla en dos por el primer ":" que se encuentre. Si falla la división, la linea se descarta, ya que no cumple el formato.

Con la división exitosa tenemos el par llave-valor, que ahora agregamos al diccionario. Todos los valores se guardan como string, ya que no hay información que permita deducir el tipo de dato.

Al terminar de procesar el texto usamos `dumps` para convertir a JSON. La función requiere un diccionario, que ya está listo.

**Demo**

```
import json

def to_json(texto):
    dicc = {}
    for linea in texto.split('\n'):
        try:
            key, value = linea.split(":", 1)
            dicc[key] = value.strip()
        except ValueError:
            pass
    return json.dumps(dicc)

ldap_answer = """
dn: cn=Total,cn=Conexiones,cn=Monitor
objectClass: monitorCounterObject
structuralObjectClass: monitorCounterObject
cn: Total
creatorsName:
modifiersName:
createTimestamp: 20210726111156Z
modifyTimestamp: 20210726111156Z
monitorCounter: 1031
entryDN: cn=Total,cn=Conexiones,cn=Monitor
subschemaSubentry: cn=Subesquema
tieneSubordinados: FALSE

# Resultado de la búsqueda
búsqueda: 2
resultado: 0 Éxito
"""

print(to_json(ldap_answer))
```

produce

```
{"dn": "cn=Total,cn=Conexiones,cn=Monitor", "objectClass": "monitorCounterObject", "structuralObjectClass": "monitorCounterObject", "cn": "Total", "creatorsName": "", "modifiersName": "", "createTimestamp": "20210726111156Z", "modifyTimestamp": "20210726111156Z", "monitorCounter": "1031", "entryDN": "cn=Total,cn=Conexiones,cn=Monitor", "subschemaSubentry": "cn=Subesquema", "tieneSubordinados": "FALSE", "b\u00fasqueda": "2", "resultado": "0 \u00c9xito"}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

#### Mejoras

Una alternativa más segura para identificar las líneas de interés es usar expresiones regulares: las líneas que interesa comienzan con una palabra seguida de ":" y un espacio en blanco. Eso se expresa con este patrón:

```
(\w+): (.+)
```

que se lee: una palabra, seguida de ":", seguida de un espacio, seguida de cualquier otra cosa hasta el final de la línea.

```
import json
import re

def to_json(texto):
    dicc = {}
    patron = re.compile("(\w+): (.+)")
    for linea in texto.split('\n'):
        match = patron.match(linea)
        if match:
            dicc[match.group(1)] = match.group(2)
    return json.dumps(dicc)
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, pero como hago para hacer la consulta esa ldap que he puesto en python?

Comment: recibes la respuesta ldap como texto, y llamas a la función to_json pasandole el texto.